# Blackberry @Override notation error

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse, I did: Source > Clean up, and did a clean up according to these rules:

- Change non static accesses to static
  members using declaring type
- Change indirect accesses to static
  members to direct accesses (accesses
  through subtypes)
- Remove unused imports
- Add missing '@Override' annotations
- Add missing '@Deprecated' annotations
- Remove unnecessary casts
- Remove unnecessary '$NON-NLS$' tags

but I can't seem to compile it anymore. I get the following error:

> Error preverifying class com.myapp.blackberry.Override
>       java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/annotation/Annotation
>   Error!: Error: preverifier failed: C:\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\bin\preverify.exe -d C:\DOCUME ...
>   Packaging project myapp failed (took 0.422 seconds)

When I hover over @Override, it gives me suggestion "Override cannot be resolved to a type"

I am not sure what to do at this point..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blackberry development is built on top of j2me, which has the language features of Java 1.3.  This means it doesn't support annotations. You can remove the @Override annotations and your code will work.  Remember these are optional although recommended anyways.

What I do, is write //@Override instead. When/If annotations are added in the future it will be easy to do a regex replace and remove the comment marks.

Comment: You should also remove the Annotation rules "Add missing @Override" and the "Add missing @Deprecated" rules as neither will work in BB dev.

Comment: Actually, when I went project > clean code, it fixed it.. thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

[Seems to be impossible:](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-9422.html)

> *The deal is Java ME uses version 1.4 of Java Language Specification.
>   You cannot use Java 5 language features.*

Seems you'll have to do without annotations...